# How to Authorization Only in Infusionsoft with Authorize.net

Tags: authorization, infusionsoft

Hello I'm using Infusionsoft and I'm wondering where I can go to change the Credit Card Transaction Types. I would like to have the Authorization Only oppose to the Authorization and capture.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I discovered that infusion-soft does not allow any other type of transaction aside from Authorize and Capture.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the API to create the transactions? If you are using  InvoiceService.chargeInvoice you can change the merchant account ID in the function parameter. You can see the ID of the merchant account inside your application.

If you need to change your merchant account inside your infusionsoft application or see the merchant account ID you must go to the Infusionsoft main menu > Ecommerce settings > Merchant Accounts then you can add new ones or edit existing ones.

Comment: hey josh thanks for taking the time to respond. After speaking with infusion and doing some investigation of my own I discovered that this is not possible with infusion soft system. They only allow Authorize and Capture.